# Problem with numeric values

Tags: ssis

I have a package where I insert a numeric table from a view into an other table.
My problem is that in my final table, my values are not the same and I do see anything particular done. 
By example :
If I have 6579207.48 in my referece table, I will have 6579207.00 in my destination table.

I know I'm not super precise hear however did anyone came accross a case like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the data types?  float is approximate, whereas numeric/decimal are exact.

Comment: Actually the poblem is resolved, it wasn't about the data types, it was about some bad mapping decision that one of my colleague made.